# XQJ and DataDirectXquery in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xquery

I am quite new to XQJ and DataDirectXquery, I would like to use eclipse for having some practice on Xquery on a JavaAPI. I am not sure which libraries or softwares do I need to install on the eclipse in order to make it work with executing xquery expressions, Can some one please guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with XQuery I've installed XQDT (xquery development toolkit) for eclipse http://www.xqdt.org/html/index
together with the SAXON http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/ interpreter. These two will make your eclipse install capable of executing xquery expressions.

You write an .xq file and launch it like a regular program from within eclipse

Once your query is ready, you can integrate SAXON in your java app, and execute the query there. See this portion of the SAXON guide: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/using-xquery.html#Embedding